# Is this a Multinomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, multinomial-distribution

I find it hard to notice when do I have a Multinomial distribution and if its possible to "transform" problems into a Multinomial distribution problems.

For example I have the following exercise:

> $15$ people come for a test
>   $21$ quizzes has been printed
>      $7$ quizzes
>   are type A
>   $7$ quizzes are type B
>   $7$ quizzes are type C
>   Each man
>   get $1$ random quiz
>
> Let X be number of people who got quiz A
>      Let Y be number of people
>   who got quiz B
>
> Write the joint probability function of X,Y

Now if it would be the joint probability function of X,Y, Z(when Z is Z=number of people who got quiz C) I could easily say its a Multinomial distribution (I think)

But now the sum X and Y is not $1$ (because some people may get C) so how can I answer this question? and how can I know when to search for a Multinomial distribution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The multinomial distribution is sampled with replacement but in your case it isn't possible to have $X>7$. Without replacement the distribution of $X$ is a multivariate hypergeometric distribution

Comment: @Hugh I'm not sure I understood, do you mean its possible to replace some data and look at it as a "different" problem and then use multinomial distribution? we didn't use the multivariate hypergometric distribution yet but isnt it only applied if the parameters are "stranger" to each other?

Comment: Suppose you have a box with the quizzes in it. The first person has an equal chance of selecting each quiz, if the person takes quiz A then the second person who selects a quiz will have a lower chance of picking A compared to the chance of picking B or C. This is selection without replacement.

Instead if the first person selects quiz A, notes their choice, and then replaces quiz A back into the box this is called selecting with replacement. The second person to select a quiz will have an equal chance of selecting A, B or C. This is why replacement is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

There are 15 people, so you know $Z=15-X-Y$, where $Z$ is the count of people who have test C.   So you have:

$$ \mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}y)= \mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}y, Z{=}15{-}x{-}y)$$

So, *if* the sampling is *with* replacement (different people may select the same puzzle) this is a multinomial distribution.

> $$\mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}y)_{\text{multinomial}} = \dbinom{15}{x,y,15-x-y} (\tfrac {1}{3})^{15}\quad\big[x\in \{1..7\}, y\in\{1..7\}\big]$$

However, *if* the sampling is *without* replacement (everyone gets a distinct quize), this is a multivariate hypergeometric distribution.

> $$\mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}y)_{\text{hypergeometric}} =\dfrac{\dbinom{7}{x}\dbinom{7}{y}\dbinom{7}{15-x-y}}{\dbinom{21}{15}}\quad\big[x\in \{1..7\}, y\in\{8{-}x..7\}\big]$$

Comment: Thanks what did you mean with the $8-x..7$? if $X=7$ then at most $y$ can be $8-7=1$?

Comment: @TheOne The maximum $Z$ can be is $7$, so when drawing without replacement, the *least* value $Y$ can be is $8-X$.  Because: $X+(8-X)+7=15$.